# Complex many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

I want to create a complex many to many relation.
I have a project model.

Each project will have a single check-list.

Checklist must have a multiple category  ( commercial, developper, designer,....) managed by super user (for creating and updating).

Each category of checklist have tasks  ( commercial : task1, task2,..... | designer: task3,task4,....) also managed by super user.

In the final, I want to have after project creation, a div with all tasks grouped by parent-category in the project homepage.

So users ( the commercial or the dev ...)  will be able to update each task belong to his category and say if yes or no is checked.

For now, I can create checklist categories and tasks with have many and belong_to.

Question: how can I do this !

Thanks .

Comment: Up please. I really need your help

Comment: Hi @delmed you need to be more clear on what you are asking.